# How to Access Qt Calender widget in qml

Tags: qml

I was trying to create a scheduler for a desktop application using qml.  I couldn't find any built in calendars for qml.So is there any method to access qt calendar widget in qml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Qt5.3 alpha` has just been [released](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.3) and in the changelog you can see that a new `Calendar` component has been added to `QtQuick.Controls`.

> Qt Quick Controls:
> The Calendar control was added. Calendar allows selection of dates from a grid of days, similar to QCalendarWidget.

This version is not production-ready yet but it should contain what you are looking for.